# How to keep track of an app's last run date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, constraints, last-modified

I am new to Javascript. I currently have index.html, stylesheet.css and div.js in my app.

In the div.js, I have some code that randomly generate a schedule for a group of people for 2 weeks. However, there's a constrain to make the schedule consistent. I mean, for example, the table is generated on May 9, and it will be good from May 9 - May 25. So if the application is run during May 9 - May 25, I need to give an alert that it has been run before, and then ask if they really want to run it again or go to the previous table.

Is there a way to achieve it with Javascript? Or do I also need other techniques?

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using any sort of server code, then no. You cannot persist it via client code alone.

For a single client case, I guess you can use cookies but I wouldn't recommend it  as it is wrong by nature. Have a look here http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp